# How to use docker android images on drone.io

Tags: android, docker, drone.io

First of all , i am very beginner in this drone and docker stuffs , so please be kind on me. Now this is the scenario

1. My organisation has a drone server ready and working.
2. When I log in into the drone server , I can see all my android repositories.
3. There is repository named "DockerTesting" which I have made just to set up the drone for Android build.(It might confuse you)
4. I have added an .drone.yml file in top-level repository "DockerTesting"
5. My .drone.yml looks like this

```js
image: docker.vokalinteractive.com/android:latest
env:
    - ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_ratsUser={{rats_user}}
    - ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_ratsPass={{rats_pass}}
    - ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk
script:
    - ./gradlew build device
notify:
  slack:
    webhook_url: https://hooks.slack.com/services/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
    channel: docker_android
    username: drone
    template: >
      {{#success build.status}}
        {{ build.author }} successfully pushed to {{ build.branch}}. Code was published.
      {{else}}
        {{ build.author }} broke the build. Code was not published.
        <{{system.link_url}}/{{repo.full_name}}/{{build.number}}|{{repo.name}}#{{build.commit}}>
      {{/success}}
```

1. I wrote this yml file myself using google
2. I am getting slack notification this is good at least for me

Below is the problem:

1. In the repository "Docker Testing" I made a syntax error, as a result the build was failed in my local machine(my laptop) in Android Studio.

   2. Now I did git push command to update this repository in my company's server
      3 The push was successful (Why?) . It should have failed as I have done a syntax error & also the build was failed in local machine